# Does VRAM matter in Resolve and Fusion (free version for PC)

Tags: graphics-cards, video, video-editing

This question is about Davinci Resolve Free (including Fusion) for Windows (PC).

I've read some comments by some users on Reddit and some discord servers saying like "free version will use only CPU so no matter what graphic card you use it won't make any difference".

Others mentioned like if your graphic card has 1G or 2GB or 12GB VRAM it won't make any difference at all because it's free version.

Further, they confused me even more. They said if you plan to use only H.264/5 media, then surely VRAM is waste. It won't make any difference.

**Is that true?** If that's true I would prefer to get a GPU with low VRAM to save my money.

**Note** (if it helps you answer better): I don't have any DSLR or high end camera. I record 1080p videos using my Nikon point and shoot compact camera which saves videos in H.264 mp4 format. And sometimes I use Samsung android phone.

Comment: This would be a question better asked of DaVinci [Blackmagic].

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah I posted there and got responses. Do you think it's good idea to post that as an answer here as well?

Comment: May as well. I'm not sure this is on topic here, but if it has an answer, it may be of use to someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for free version DaVinci Resolve do not use GPU for acceleration. Also you will be limited in FX because some of them depend on GPU to do the work (noise reduction, lens flares, lens reflections, dirt removal, analog damage, face refinement, patch replacer, film grain and de-flickering)